# Highcharts export all data in Stockchart

Tags: csv, highcharts, export-to-csv

I have a simple question about exporting module of Highcharts/Stockchart.
It's possible export all data in CSV independient of zoom in chart? I mean, if I have a Stockchart, and I set "All" option, I can see, i.e,
6 months and the difference between points (pointinterval) in this moment is 1 hour. If I set "1W" (one week), zoom chart show points with 
difference of 15 minutes.
Array data, as we can see, has really values each 5 minutes, just Stockchart show me intervals in function of zoom.

Question is, if I set "ALL", Can I export all original data, (points each 5 minutes)? Now, export module give me a .csv with the values I see
in the chart, If I have "ALL" I have values each 1 hour.

I tried to include "Navigator" inside the module export option but problem is sometimes, the export data is wrong and time interval is totally
wrong build (in .csv download).

I hope you can understand me! Hard to explain...

Thanks for the support,

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit source code of `exportCSV.js` file and find a loop inside, which refers to a data array instead options.points. I prepared you a demo how it should work.

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/eru5w3jv/3/